# How to change built-in type() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

It is possible to changing the default behavior of the `type()`?
This is what happens now:

```
simple_string = "this is a simple string"
type(simple_string)
<class 'str'>
```

This is how a I want it to work or something similar:

```
simple_string = "this is a simple string"
type(simple_string)
"str"
```

Comment: You shouldn't change the behavior of built-in functions, because other parts of the application that use the function will break.

Comment: If you want the name of the class, just ask for it: `type(simple_string).__name__`

Comment: well, that's was exactly what i need it, thanksss :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `__name__` property

```
 simple_string = "this is a simple string"
 type(simple_string).__name__

>>> 'str'
```

Answer (score 3):

In python, [everything is an object](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python-type-object#:%7E:text=Everything%20in%20Python%20is%20an%20object%20including%20classes.&text=If%20single%20argument%20type(obj,returns%20a%20new%20type%20object.).

The `type()` function simply returns a reference to the class of which the object is an instance of. Think of the class like the mold and the object as something created from that mold.

The type() function will return a python object reference to the class from which the object is derived. To get the name of the class (in this case 'str'), you can access the **name** property as follows:

```
my_class = type('my string')
my_class_name = class.__name__
```